# Unir consultas en una sola, ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

tengo estas consultas:

**`consultaA:`**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FK_HD, t1.DE_rfc
FROM tbl_DE t1
WHERE (((t1.FK_HD)=105))
GROUP BY t1.FK_HD, t1.DE_rfc
HAVING (((Sum(t1.DE_cantidad))<>0))
ORDER BY t1.DE_rfc;
```

**`consultaB:`**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.FK_HD, t2.DE_rfc
FROM tbl_DE t2
WHERE (((t2.FK_HD)=106));
```

De las dos consultas hago una comparacion usando el nombre de las mismas.

**`Comparacion`**

```
SELECT consultaA.DE_rfc
FROM consultaA LEFT JOIN consultaB ON consultaA.DE_rfc = consultaB.DE_rfc
WHERE (((consultaB.DE_rfc) Is Null))
```

***Esta consulta me devuelve 48 registros.***

---

Por cuestiones de mi aplicacion tengo que realizar una SOLA consulta y lo he intentado de esta manera:

```
SELECT DE_rfc FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.FK_HD, t1.DE_rfc
FROM tbl_DE t1
WHERE (((t1.FK_HD)=105))
GROUP BY t1.FK_HD, t1.DE_rfc
HAVING (((Sum(t1.DE_cantidad))<>0))) a LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.FK_HD, t2.DE_rfc
FROM tbl_DE t2
WHERE (((t2.FK_HD)=106))) b ON a.DE_rfc = b.DE_rfc WHERE (((b.DE_rfc) Is Null))
```

Pero no me arroja ningun resultado, espero me puedan orientar cual es mi error ya que no logro decifrarlo.

Comment: podras mostrarnos los datos? a simple vista no se ve nada mal. Igual en esta pregunta vb.net no tiene nada que ver.. es sql y access...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

la única diferencia que yo veo entre tu consulta **`comparación`** y la última es :

```
SELECT consultaA.DE_rfc ...

SELECT DE_rfc FROM..
```

El conflicto podria darse de que **DE_rfc** tienes en las dos consultas (A y B) entonces tienes que especificar de cual consulta tendrias que obtener la columna.

Prueba con esto y comentas que tal:

```
SELECT a.DE_rfc FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.FK_HD, t1.DE_rfc
FROM tbl_DE t1
WHERE (((t1.FK_HD)=105))
GROUP BY t1.FK_HD, t1.DE_rfc
HAVING (((Sum(t1.DE_cantidad))<>0))) a LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.FK_HD, t2.DE_rfc
FROM tbl_DE t2
WHERE (((t2.FK_HD)=106))) b ON a.DE_rfc = b.DE_rfc WHERE (((b.DE_rfc) Is Null))
```